# boost и векторы

Tags: c++, boost

Возникла необходимость в использовании векторов (имеется ввиду векторы из геометрии) с сответственными операциями, вроде вычитания, сложения, перемножения и т.д. Написать самому контейнер не проблема, но есть ли в `boost` такой? Смотрел `boost/geometry` но что-то не нашел подходящего.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В boost есть раздел [Basic Linear Algebra Library](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/index.html), думаю, вам туда.

Answer (score 1):

Если вам нужны примитивы для работы с 3D объектами (графика и т.д.) - есть [Boost QVM](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/qvm/doc/index.html) (2D, 3D, 4D вектора и матрицы). Если вам нужна библиотека для работы с матрицами в принципе - смотрите в сторону [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/GettingStarted.html). Boost uBLAS хотя и предоставляет более универсальные интерфейсы, по удобству и производительности сильно уступает (по производительности, к сожалению, даже ручным реализациям матриц уступает из-за некоторых ограничений абстракций).

Если вам нужно просто сложить или попарно перемножить два вектора - есть `std::valarray`